# Expression to convert numeric values: System.InvalidCastException: > Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Int64'

Tags: c#, lambda, .net-core, casting, expression-trees

I'm trying to create an expression to convert some numeric values. Here is what I have tried:

```
public object ConvertValue(object value, Type targetType) {
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "p"); // "p"
    var convert = Expression.Convert(parameter, targetType); // Convert(p, Int64)
    var targetConvert = Expression.Convert(convert, typeof(object)); // Convert(Convert(p, Int64), Object)
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object,object>>(targetConvert, parameter); // p => Convert(Convert(p, Int64), Object)
    var method = lambda.Compile();
    var result = method(value); // HERE I GET THE ERROR!
    return result;
}
```

But when I call it, as this simple test:

```
[Fact]
public void TestConvert() {
    var result = ConvertValue(23, typeof(long));
    Assert.Equal(typeof(long), result.GetType());
}
```

I get the error:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidCastException:
>   Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Int64'.
>   at lambda_method(Closure , Object ) bla bla bla...

Any idea what's happening here and what `Int32` cannot be cast to `Int64`? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Technically, under the hood, both are different types and cannot be casted, just as you cannot cast `string` to `int`. What usually happens is that what _looks_ like a cast in C# can be any of the following things: A type-cast, an invocation of an explicit conversion operator (which is what happens with numeric conversions like "casting" `int` to `long`), boxing a value type, or unboxing a value type. It can be a bit confusing that all those things share the same syntax.

Comment: @Joey thanks to the description. I forgot that. Have you any idea how to fix the expression?

Comment: How is this intended to be different from the built-in [`Convert.ChangeType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.changetype?view=netframework-4.8) method?

Answer (score 0):

The following takes advantage of `Convert.ChangeType` to provide more flexibility with the conversions.

The code comments document what is being done.

```
public object ConvertValue(object value, Type targetType){
    var valueType = value.GetType();
    // Func<TValue,TTarget>
    var delegateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(valueType, targetType);
    var convert = typeof(Convert).GetMethod("ChangeType", new[] { typeof(object), typeof(Type) });
    // TValue p
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(valueType, "p");
    // Convert.ChangeType(Convert(p), targetType);
    var changeType = Expression.Call(convert, Expression.Convert(parameter, typeof(object)), Expression.Constant(targetType));
    // (TTarget)Convert.ChangeType(Convert(p), targetType);
    var body = Expression.Convert(changeType, targetType);
    //Func<TValue,TTarget> = TValue p => (TTarget)Convert.ChangeType(Convert(p), targetType);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda(delegateType, body, parameter);
    var method = lambda.Compile();
    var result = method.DynamicInvoke(value);
    return result;
}
```

The following basic tests all passed when exercised

```
[TestMethod]
public void Should_Convert_Int_To_Long() {
    var expected = typeof(long);
    var actual = ConvertValue(23, expected);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual.GetType());
}

[TestMethod]
public void Should_Convert_Long_To_Int() {
    var expected = typeof(int);
    var actual = ConvertValue((long)23, expected);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual.GetType());
}

[TestMethod]
public void Should_Convert_String_To_Long() {
    var expected = typeof(long);
    var actual = ConvertValue("23", expected);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual.GetType());
}

[TestMethod]
public void Should_Convert_String_To_Int() {
    var expected = typeof(int);
    var actual = ConvertValue("23", expected);
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual.GetType());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you try to do is `(int64)(object)23` and it won't work because `23` is of type `int32`. You can pass `23L` literal and it'll work:

```
ConvertValue(23L, typeof(long));
```

To make your code work, you need to call convert from `int32` to `int64` after unboxing:

```
public static object ConvertValue(object value, Type targetType) {
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "p"); // "p"
    var convert = Expression.Convert(Expression.Convert(parameter, value.GetType()), targetType); // Convert(p, Int64)
    var targetConvert = Expression.Convert(convert, typeof(object)); // Convert(Convert(p, Int64), Object)
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object,object>>(targetConvert, parameter); // p => Convert(Convert(p, Int64), Object)
    var method = lambda.Compile();
    var result = method(value);
    return result;
}
```